# Adding css style by jquery corrupt carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is all javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/templates/default/_scripts/jquery.innerfade.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function(){
        $('.rotation ul').addClass('image_rotation');
        $('.image_rotation').css("display","block");
        $('.image_rotation').innerfade({
            speed: 'slow',
            timeout: 10000,
            type: 'sequence'
        });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var save_url = "background-font-size-save.html"
 $(document).ready(function () {
  /*  Images: rotate, frame, shadow  */
  $('.rotation ul li img').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":first-child")) {
      var m_left=0;
      var m_top=0;
    }
    else {
      var m_left=0;
      var m_top=0;
      m_left = parseInt($(this).prev().attr("width")) + parseInt($(this).prev().css('margin-left'));
      if (parseInt(m_left)+parseInt($(this).attr("width")) > 430) {
        m_left=0;
        m_top=250-parseInt($(this).attr("height"));
      }
    }
    var r_rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) - 5;
    $(this).css({'border':'5px #ffffff solid','border-radius':'10px','transform':'rotate('+r_rand+'deg)','-moz-transform':'rotate('+r_rand+'deg)','-webkit-transform':'rotate('+r_rand+'deg)','-ms-transform':'rotate('+r_rand+'deg)','box-shadow':'4px 4px 10px -3px #000000','position':'absolute','margin':m_top+'px 0 0 '+m_left+'px'});
  });
  /*  images end  */
  background(5);
  $('html').css('font-size', 14);
  var originalFontSize = $('html').css('font-size');
 });
 function background(n) { $('.wrap').css("background","url(assets/templates/default/images/bg"+n+".jpg)"); $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: save_url, data: { background: n } }); return false; }
 function big_font() {
  var currentFontSize = $('html').css('font-size');
  var currentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(currentFontSize, 10);
  var newFontSize = currentFontSizeNum*1.1;
  $('html').css('font-size', newFontSize);
  $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: save_url, data: { font_size: newFontSize } });
  return false;
 }
 function small_font() {
  var currentFontSize = $('html').css('font-size');
  var currentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(currentFontSize, 10);
  var newFontSize = currentFontSizeNum*0.9;
  $('html').css('font-size', newFontSize);
  $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: save_url, data: { font_size: newFontSize } });
  return false;
 }
</script>
```

I have few images, which i want to rotate, add border, shadow. But I also use jquery plugin to rotate li content. Html look like this:

```
<div class="rotation">
 <ul>
  <li><img src=".." width=".." height=".." /></li>
  <li><img src=".." width=".." height=".." /><img src=".." width=".." height=".." /></li>
  <li><img src=".." width=".." height=".." /><img src=".." width=".." height=".." /><img src=".." width=".." height=".." /></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Problem I have is if i add to each image shadow, rotate it, border, using this jquery code, content from each li tags doesnt disappear and it show all the time. If i remove code which add shadow, border etc. it show one li content in the same time. Why is that? How can i add all my style to each image without corrupting carousel?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to edit the plugin and look for how/where it generates the rendering for the elements and append your new styles. Some plugins have attributes you can pass in for customization some do not.